# How to get php string values already set into an array

Tags: php, laravel, query-builder

I get some values from laravel query builder. I would like to get and set these values into somewhere of my code. So **i get undefined index exception** message with the following codes :

laravel query :

```
$generatedRowValue = DB::table('myTableName')
                         ->where('id', '=', 'someValue')
                         ->where('anyOtherValue', '=', 'anotherValue')
                         ->get();
```

I want to reach the values set in $generatedRowValue variable.

P.S. : Yeah i can get the values from the query, checked it out with var_dump(); dd(); etc. and i know **my values are not undefined**. 
I'm new on this platform so i don't know how to reach these values.

Any help would be appreciated.

---UPDATE---

This is a simple HTML file which includes php partially.

```
<?php
   $html = new simple_html_dom();
   $html->load('<input type="text" value="'.$generatedRowValue['thevalueName'].'">')
?>
```

So i need $generatedRowValue['thevalueName'] 's value.

Comment: How you pass your `$generatedRowValue` to your view?

Comment: `get()` returns an *array* of objects. I think you want to use `first()` instead.

Comment: I'm using PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser. You can check it out : http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm

Comment: Where you want to use your `$generatedRowValue` ? to your view? to your controller and please add those on your question.

Comment: What has `PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser` got to do with your question?

Comment: @MarkBaker i'm just using that one another parts of my projects and i need to ask that way to learn.

Comment: @SetKyarWaLar i updated for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get()` returns an array of objects. I think you want to use `first()` instead since you only expect one result.

```
$generatedRowValue = DB::table('myTableName')
                     ->where('id', '=', 'someValue')
                     ->where('anyOtherValue', '=', 'anotherValue')
                     ->first();
```

By the way, you can also use the object syntax in your view (if you want)

```
$generatedRowValue->thevalueName
```

Comment: I already found the $x->valuename syntax from laravel docs, but thanks for your help.